# Using requests.get and enabling stream -- how to avoid a memory leak on an error?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm making a request using the Python requests lib and enabling the stream.
My understanding is that I need to close response to avoid a memory leak, however on an error (e.g. name resolution of a domain [when it doesn't exist]), how do I do this?

```
try:
    with requests.get(url, headers = self.user_agent, timeout = 3, stream = True) as response:
    ...
except Exception as error:
    self.echo(f"get request failed for url \"{url}\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, the `__exit__` method will be called in case of Exception too

It's signature is `def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):`

- in case of normal exiting, the 3 parameters will be `None`
- in case of an exception, you'll get the exception type, objet and traceback

Comment: So no memory leak will occur when there's an error?